# Get sum of total amount from a table column that coming from a api

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have a api with a unique number, the number is different, so when i call api with this unique number, i get back data, i am showing data in table. the table has a column name "amount".
as its dynamic data coming from an api, i am just stucked how i can show total amount in the very bottom of the table. i am using laravel.

my code sample

```
<table class="table table-one">
       <thead class="table-success">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Inst. No.</th>
                <th scope="col">PR No.</th>
                <th scope="col">PR Date</th>
                 <th scope="col">Prem. Amt.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead><!-- ends: thead -->
        <tbody>

         @foreach ($results['polinfo'] as $data) 
          @foreach ($data['poldata'] as $res)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{$res['INSTALNO']}}</th>
                <td>{{$res['PR_NO']}}</td>
                <td>{{$res['PR_DATE']}}</td>
                <td>{{$res['AMOUNT']}}</td>
            </tr>
       @endforeach
         @endforeach

        </tbody><!-- ends: tbody -->
    </table>
```

i have to calcualte all {{$res['AMOUNT']}} and have to show it as total amount.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Totals should be added after foreach loops, that's true for general programming. General total after outermost foreach, and subtotals after inner foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the value only after the `foreach` you can get away with a separate variable to which to add the amounts:

```
@php($amount = 0)

@foreach ($results['polinfo'] as $data) 
    @foreach ($data['poldata'] as $res)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{$res['INSTALNO']}}</th>
            <td>{{$res['PR_NO']}}</td>
            <td>{{$res['PR_DATE']}}</td>
            <td>{{$res['AMOUNT']}}</td>
        </tr>
        
        @php($amount += (int) $res['AMOUNT'])
    @endforeach
@endforeach

Amount: {{ $amount }}
```